# linux - Burn bootable dvd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, linux-mint, dvd

I try to burn a bootable dvd for linux mint mate 17.1.

I tried 3 tools:

- Braseo (ubuntu/mint)
- windows disk image burner (win7)
- Nero (a tool for windows)

Only the image burned by Nero succeed to boot linux mint mate from dvd.
The other 2 solution can't find something when try booting from dvd.

**My question is:**

Is there a tool on linux (ubuntu/mint) could do this task similar as Nero on windows?

Comment: Are you trying to burn an ISO image, or to build your own bootable DVD? As long as you configure the tool to write a pre-existing ISO image it should work.

Comment: @wurtel I downloaded `linux mint mate 17.1` iso image file, I want to install it on a new machine, so I am trying to burn the iso into a DVD, bootable, so that I can use it to install on the new machine.

Comment: I usually just do `growisofs -Z /dev/dvd=filename.iso` on linux.

Comment: @wurtel I did a little google according to your comment, and found this http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1089, it seems growisofs is a solution on linux mint, thx. I have wasted 3 dvd images today ... I will try it out for next mint release :)

Comment: Note also that many systems can boot from a USB stick. At least Debian ISO images are prepared for use on DVDs and on USB sticks; in that case just copy the ISO image to the USB stick: `dd if=filename.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=1024k` and MAKE SURE that you replace `sdb` with your real USB stick, check `dmesg` output after insertion.

Answer (score 1):

I can name a few programs used to burn bootables. If you are trying to burn a Windows Bootable, honestly, good luck because it is hell.

In Linux distros, the most popular 'dd' command can be used in almost 100% of cases for example: sudo dd status=progress if=/path/to/image/file/iso/img/etc of=/dev/sr0. sr0 being the dev path to the cd-rom containing the blank disk. for a flash drive (recommended 4GB since 99% image files don't exceed 4GB), instead of 'sr0', it would be sdx, x appointing the correct dev path to the flash drive. Example: sda, sdb, sdc, sdd, sde, sdf. NEVER use sda as it is the first internal HDD. have fun.

for Windows, use Rufus. Point blank.

for MacOS, you can also use the 'dd' command.

for programs of linux:
1. Etcher is mine and most's perferance.
2. dd command